# Merge without duplicate on right table

Tags: python, pandas

I need help with following join in Pandas :

My first table has duplicate date and second got unique. When I merged the two tables by **Date**, second table gets duplicate values instead of first match and rest should be `NaN`.

Does anyone knows how to do it with Python?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your question properly. Don't forget to include **your effort**.

Comment: You can do it with Python, of course, just not with pandas.  What you're asking for is not how a 'join' works.

Answer (score 0):

Do a [merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) on `Date` and `x` column:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2-Jul', '2-Jul', '3-Jul'],
                    'x': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'Alice'],
                    'y': [5, 9, 7]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2-Jul', '3-Jul'],
                    'x': ['Bob', 'Alice'],
                    'z': [2, 8]})

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Date', 'x'])
```

```
# print(df3)
    Date      x  y  z
0  2-Jul    Bob  5  2
1  2-Jul    Bob  9  2
2  3-Jul  Alice  7  8
```

[pandas.DataFrame.duplicated()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) returns boolean Series denoting duplicate rows. `keep=first` marks duplicates as True except for the first occurrence. The default value of `keep` is first, so you can omit this.

[pandas.DataFrame.mask()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) replaces values where the condition is True.

```py
df3['z'].mask(df3.duplicated(subset=['Date', 'x'], keep='first'), inplace=True)
```

```
# print(df3)
    Date      x  y    z
0  2-Jul    Bob  5  2.0
1  2-Jul    Bob  9  NaN
2  3-Jul  Alice  7  8.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! you save me. I appreciated a lot!!!!!!!!! Your are the best :)

Comment: @bobkevin **If your question is solved**, say thank you by ***accepting** the solution that is **best for your needs***. The **accept check** is below the up/down arrow at the top left of the answer. A new solution can be accepted if a better one shows up. If you have a reputation of 15 or greater, you may also vote on the quality of an answer, with the up or down arrow. **Leave a comment if a solution doesn't answer the question**. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?. Thank you.